# I started making a qt6 widget application. How do I get it to start in the upper right corner of the screen when I run the application

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

⁸I started making a qt6 widget application. How do I get it to start in the upper right corner of the screen when I run the application.I've been struggling for hours but couldn't find the appropriate code to do this with cmake.Is there a way to install the cmake QDesktopWidget library ?
I hoped that the code in the bold text would start in the upper right corner, but it was not as I expected, I can't find the problem.

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "./ui_widget.h"
#include <QScreen>
#include <QRect>
#include <QSize>
#include <QApplication>


Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowType::FramelessWindowHint);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    this->setStyleSheet(".QFrame{background-color: red; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px;}");
       QRect sc = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry();
       QWidget::move(sc.top( ),sc.right());
       Widget::show();

}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
this->move(QApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry().right()- this->rect().right(),
           QApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry().top()- this->rect().top());
```

Comment: In the end, even though I searched for hours, he did not create such a simple code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the window is the size of the screen, swapping sc.top() and sc.right() and subtracting the width of the widget from sc.right() should work

This plus removing either the call to setWindowFlags or to setAttribute will display the widget in the top right corner
Alternatively you can add something to display in the widget, and that would show up, its just that the combination makes the widget itself invisible

Comment: I tried many times, but when I run the application, it completely disappears from the screen.

Comment: Changing QWidget::move(sc.top( ),sc.right()); to QWidget::move(sc.right( ) - this->width(),sc.top()); doesn't work?

Comment: Did some experimenting, removing either the set window flags call or set attribute call will display the widget. Will edit answer with this as well